# Remove "display name" field in woocommerce account details

Tags: woocommerce

I'd like to remove the field "Display name" in WooCommerce 4.2.0 account details page and other pages.

I added this to my functions.php to make it not mandatory, but I still see the little red asterisk next to the field.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_save_account_details_required_fields', 'wc_save_account_details_required_fields' );
function wc_save_account_details_required_fields( $required_fields ){
    unset( $required_fields['account_display_name'] );
    return $required_fields;
}
```

Comment: This requires to override via your active theme the template file [`myaccount/form-edit-account.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.5.2/templates/myaccount/form-edit-account.php) where you will be able to make changes or remove the [display name field](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.5.2/templates/myaccount/form-edit-account.php#L36-L39)

Comment: ok thank you. Do you think it will affect the customer registering process ?

Comment: I don't think, but I am not sure, so try it.

Comment: ok I'll try, thanks

Comment: I am trying for a while. It seems stable. Thanks for your help @LoicTheAztec ;)

Comment: Just deleting it from form-edit-account.php will not work, FYI, doing so returns an error from the form's validation upon trying to save.